# No compatible binary build found for this package

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteoric

When I run both meteor add for both `meteoric:ionic-sass` and `meteoric:ionicons.-sass`, it shows the error below.

```
=> Errors while adding packages:

While checking for stevezhu:sass@1.3.7:
error: No compatible binary build found for this package. Contact the
package author and ask them to publish it for your platform.
```

I use a windows machine by the way..is that the problem? I have also posted on the Github page but I think it is not maintained or something.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue with a different package while trying to work on a Windows machine. I ended up calling `meteor update` while in the directory for the meteor project I was working on and that fixed it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did try this too but didn't work. It has something to do with meteor platform and updating of versions. I spoke to the package creator and will post the solution here asap if it works.